# How to Backup a PostgreSQL Database From a Docker Container Using DBeaver?

Tags: 20.04, docker, postgresql

I have a Postgres database running in a docker container in my machine (running Ubuntu 20.04 Beta) and I need to make a backup of it.

I'm using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/) 7.0.2 to manage the database, but when I try to use the backup tool, it asks me to set a native client. The only option I have when I click the drop list is *browse*, but then it prompts me this window:

[picture of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajudL.png)

I have no idea of what I need to put here; didn't find anything useful on the documentation; and in every tutorial I find on the web, the native client drop list has other options, which is not my case. Can someone help?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem.

Comment: I tried to find a solution for some time, but had no luck. In the end I just copied some stuff to a new database. There wasn't many information, so it was a bit faster than a terminal workaround, but it's not a good idea for big databases.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to accomplish this the same way you did, and had the same problem. Unfortunately, *I did not find a way to resolve the issue with DBeaver*, so this may not be what you are looking for, but this answer got me what I needed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29913462/9843399. Here it is with slight editing:

### Backup your database

```
docker exec -t <your-db-container> pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump_`date +%d-%m-%Y"_"%H_%M_%S`.sql
```

### Restore your database

```
cat your_dump.sql | docker exec -i <your-db-container> psql -U postgres
```

(Note: I had to recreate my schema before the restore worked properly. On my version you can do this in DBeaver like: click your db > right-click on "Schemas" > click "Create New Schema")